# ld cannot find shared library

Tags: shared-library, g++, ld

Note: I visited many topics with questions *similar* to this one, although solutions chosen as accepted were all things I've **already tried**, so please, consider this before marking as duplicate.

Also, I'm new to Linux in general, so feel free to correct me if I say something fundamentally incorrect.

### The problem:

I'm trying to create and use a c++ **shared library** and while the "create" part seems to be done, while trying to link against it, **ld cannot see it**.

Here's what I've already managed to do:

1. Compiled all .cpp files with -fPIC explicitly stated
2. Created the library with

   g++ -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libcustom_program_options.so.1 -o
   libcustom_program_options.so.1.0.1 *.o
3. Ran ldconfig to update the loader cache like this:

   sudo ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib

And when I try to link the library against my test program:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -L /usr/local/lib -l libcustom_program_options
```

Here's what happens:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcustom_program_options
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

---

Note: I wasn't sure if ld was looking for the library's **full-name** or **soname** or maybe the **"name between lib- and .so.{version}"**, so I tried each one of those. Didn't help either.

Comment: Did you try `-lcustom_program_options`? the `l` is usually expanded to `lib` (so for example `-lm` links `libm.so` and so on)

Comment: Yes, I did. By saying "name between lib- and .so.{version}" I meant exactly that: -lcustom_program_options. I think  I tried all the possible combinations of syntaxes, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve it.

Once I checked **what file the linker is actually expecting to find**, I knew what to do next.

I did it by calling:

```
ld -L/usr/local/lib -lcustom_program_options --verbose
```

Where **/usr/local/lib** is the directory I put the library in, and **custom_program_options** is the name of the library stripped of the lib- prefix and all prefixes (i.e. extension and version).

As it printed a list of all considered directories along with the exact expected file name, I knew that it was looking for **libcustom_program_options.so**, whilst calling ldconfig (mentioned in the OP) set a link only between **libcustom_program_options.so.1** and **libcustom_program_options.so.1.0.1** (note the version number).

The file ld was trying to find indeed never existed.

The solution was to create the link manually:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libcustom_program_options.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libcustom_program_options.so
```

So this pretty much solved it. The culprit was me not knowing what was the exact filename sought by the linker.